# Flip SQL Column value from open to closed and vice-versa in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

Can someone please guide me with below query.

on Running one stored proc I get below table.

[image]

Like above more than 1000 rows are returned while executing the SP. 
I am trying to flip State values for IP address in MonthYear JAN-2013 only. So outcome will be 
So outcome will be

[image]

I tried with SQL Update statement with CASE but not sure if there is any other way of doing this.

Comment: Added tags as per marc_s.. Above query is specific for Microsoft SQL Server 2012 db, I didnt see 2012 tag so tagged with sql server 2008 one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want another way to do it when case is perfectly logical and legible.

```
update tbl
set state = case when 'open' then 'closed'
                 when 'closed' then 'open' end
where monthyear = 'JAN-2013'
```

Comment: After running your code there will be no closed status no more. All records will be open